# Using SQL query to run a current balance

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating some stored procedures for the small non-profit I work for. We have one table that holds the information for our yearly budget, including how much is budgeted for each line item (i.e., "Promotional Materials, 500"). There is another table in which all of our expenses are recorded, along with which budget line they came from. I'd like to run a stored procedure that subtracts all the expenses from that budget line against the starting budget amount from the other table. The query I came up with to test the procedure is this:

```
SELECT b.budget_line_ID, 
       b.budget_line_name, 
       b.[2017_amount] - e.amount AS CurrentBalance
FROM budget_detail AS b
INNER JOIN expenses AS e ON b.budget_line_ID = e.budget_line_id
WHERE e.budget_line_id = 4;
```

However, when I run the query, the right columns appear but there is no information in them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is there a budget_line_id=4 in both tables? Also, it sounds like you may want to do b.[2017_amount] - sum(e.amount) instead...BTW thanks for working with non-profits

Comment: Do you have that budget_line_id = 4 in both tables? `INNER JOIN` requires it to be present on both tables or else it will not return anything.

Comment: on table `b` you have it as `budget_line_ID` but on `e` it's `budget_line_id` is this correct?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following perhaps?

```
DECLARE @budget_line_id INT = 4;

SELECT 
    b.budget_line_id,
    b.budget_line_name,
    CurrentBalance = b.[2017_amount] - te.amount
FROM 
    dbo.budget_detail b
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            amount = SUM(e.amount )
        FROM 
            dbo.expenses  e
        WHERE 
            b.budget_line_ID = e.budget_line_id
            AND e.budget_line_id = @budget_line_id
        ) te
WHERE 
    b.budget_line_id = @budget_line_id;
```

---

EDIT: Providing 2 alternate methods of doing the same thing.

```
-- JOIN to a derived table...
SELECT 
    b.budget_line_id,
    b.budget_line_name,
    CurrentBalance = b.[2017_amount] - te.amount
FROM 
    dbo.budget_detail b
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
            e.budget_line_id,
            amount = SUM(e.amount )
        FROM 
            dbo.expenses  e
        WHERE
            e.budget_line_id = @budget_line_id
        GROUP BY 
            e.budget_line_id
        ) te
        ON b.budget_line_id = te.budget_line_id
WHERE 
    b.budget_line_id = @budget_line_id;
```

...

```
-- Correlated sub-query in the SELECT...
SELECT 
    b.budget_line_id,
    b.budget_line_name,
    CurrentBalance = b.[2017_amount] 
        - (SELECT 
            amount = SUM(e.amount )
        FROM 
            dbo.expenses  e
        WHERE 
            b.budget_line_ID = e.budget_line_id
            AND e.budget_line_id = @budget_line_id
        )
FROM 
    dbo.budget_detail b
WHERE 
    b.budget_line_id = @budget_line_id;
```

Comment: IT WORKED!! Thank you so much! Now, to figure out how you made it work so that I can actually learn something ;)

Comment: The CROSS APPLY simply allows the use a correlated sub-query in the from clause. In this case, we're creating a SUM of e.amount for every budget_line_id  in the outer query. Here, it isn't absolutely necessary as there are other way to write this and get the same results. I'll update my original answer to demonstrate the more traditional JOIN to a derived table and correlated sub-query in the SELECT. Let me know if you have any questions.